# validates_format_of :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https)) issue

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a two validation in my model abc.rb

```
validates_format_of :url, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))
validates_format_of :targetUrl, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))

validates_format_of :targetUrl
```

is not validating the input. whatever I input it accepts. Same issue I am having on other model where I have a validation 
`validates_format_of :website, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))`.
 I am not able to figure out why validation failing for
`validates_format_of :targetUrl, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))` and `validates_format_of :website, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))`.

Any hints will be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the regex formatting that way. Use something like:

```
validates :website, format: { with: /(http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\#\/\_]+[\.][a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\#\/\_]+/i }
```

And obviously use whatever regex you like!

Comment: Same issue. I am curious why same validation not working on other fields.

Comment: Same issue as what?  This is the validation I use in one of my applications, so it definitely works...

Comment: its not validating the url. I type garbage it accepts. Plus I am not looking for new validation. I am want to know why same validation format works for one field and not working for other.

Comment: Make sure you are calling all the validations for a given field in the same place.  In your case, calling `validates_format_of` more than once will simply override the others.

Comment: I already tried that and that didnt help. In one of the model this validation 'validates_format_of :website, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))' doesn't work at all.

Comment: I suggested that you not use that format; use the format I posted for all of your validations instead.  You can chain onto each, e.g. `validates :website, length: { maximum: 50 }, format: { with: /(http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\#\/\_]+[\.][a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\#\/\_]+/i, message: "must be http:// or https:// and without additional characters (?, %, =, etc)" }, allow_blank: true`